# Dynamically set a struct field to a slice value using reflect

Tags: go, struct, reflection

I have the following code snippet that after going some reflection, it sets a struct's field to a string value

```golang
                switch fType := v.(type) {
                case MyCompositeFlagString:
                    s, ok := userInput.(string)
                    if !ok {
                        log.Printf("Erroneous input type:%T and input value: %v\n", userInput, userInput)
                        return ErrUnexpectedInput
                    }
                    valueField := values.Elem().Field(i).FieldByName("MyFlagString").FieldByName("Value")
                    valueField.SetString(s)
```

I don't see any `SetSlice` method in `reflect` package.

How can I perform the above operation when the `valueField` is of type `[]string` ?

Comment: Use the [`Set`](https://golang.org/pkg/reflect/#Value.Set) method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`Value.SetString()`](https://golang.org/pkg/reflect/#Value.SetString) is a convenience method for setting `string` values. There isn't a separate method for *all* types for obvious reasons, but there is a "generic" [`Value.Set()`](https://golang.org/pkg/reflect/#Value.Set) method, you may use that. You just have to obtain a `reflect.Value` from the value you want to set:

```
var someSlice ...
valueField.Set(reflect.ValueOf(someSlice))
```